# popuponstart jailbreak tweak by ziph0n

Tags: jailbreak, theos

Jailblog.co isn't opening since a week! Seems to have gone down. Anybody know how to create a preference pane for the popuponstart tweak by ziph0n in that blog?

[This is the tweak.xm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JaqJ.png)

There was a tutorial on the site on how to create the preference pane but unfortunately now it is not opening! Do help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create a tweak with an enable and disable switch. Look at this video for a simple preferable pane and how to make it. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nBQuz7TvecA

Comment: Elias perfect. Now if you could tell me how to link a preference Bundle with a tweak, it'd be awesome. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Type $THEOS/bin/nic.pl in Terminal after logging in as root
The select 3 and fill out the info
Look in /var/mobile/whateveryounamedit

Comment: Ellas I know how to create a preference template. I was talking about the code to be written. Could you please help me there?